# Данные в ответе на Ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax

привет. есть код

```
                if (data) 
                {
                    var list = jQuery('<ul />').attr('class', 'list-ul');
                    $("body").append(list);
                    list.text(data);
                }
```

`if` срабатывает, если приходят данные, но если я сделаю

```
if(!data)
{
  ///
}
```

то не работает. Также пробовал сравнивать данные с пустой строкой   `""`,
писал `data == ""` и `data === ""`, ничего не меняется. Как правильно определить, что в ответ не пришло данных на запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у вас приходят пробелы в строке и соответственно строка уже не есть пустая. Используйте `String.trim()` для удаления лишних пробельных символов:

```js
var data = "   ";

data = data.trim();

if (!data) {
   console.log('error');
} else {
   var list = jQuery('<ul />').attr('class', 'list-ul');
   $("test").append(list);
   list.text(data);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Вы не проверяли 'else' после вашего 'if'?

#### Можно если так:

```
if(data)
{
    var list = jQuery('').attr('class', 'list-ul');
    $("body").append(list);
    list.text(data);
} else {
  // Тут если данные не приходят
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы проблема решилась сама по себе.
Конструкция

```
if (data != "") 
{
  ///
}
else
{
  ///
}
```

раньше почему то не работавшая сейчас хорошо работает.